# How to change a div's property by onclick event?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I want to change container's property by clicking on an image.
Why this doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeMargin(){
        document.getElementById("container").style.margin.top="100px";
    }
</script>

<div id="container">
    <img id="btnRight" src="img/btnRight.png" onclick="changeMargin()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should be

```
.marginTop="100px";
```

Full code:

```
function changeMargin() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.marginTop = "100px";
}
```

Comment: Yes, solved. Thanks. But dw didn't tell me aobut syntax error.

Comment: @Alice it's not a `SyntaxError`, your code is grammatically correct.

Comment: what kind of error is then. How dw know that code has an error if the syntax is correct.

Comment: @ Jonathan what is the better solution instead of dw ?

Comment: @Alice SyntaxErrors are just one type of errors, they are the only errors that can be seen just by looking at the code. For other errors, the code must be executed. This however doesn't cause an error because it's completely legit to set a property of a string. It just doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: @Alice you should look into google chrome and its developer tools if you want a good debugging experience. Or firefox and firebug but I can't vouch for them.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.margin.top="100px";
```

To:

```
document.getElementById("container").style.marginTop="100px";
```